# Principal Axis and Conservation of Angular Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

In the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms_lUMIwzFg), the rotation of the wooden block around the principal axis with intermediate moment of inertia is an unstable rotation, where the axis of rotation and therefore the angular velocity vector changes direction.
Since the axis is a principal axis, we know the eigenvector equation:
$$\vec L = L\vec e_l = \lambda\vec \omega=\lambda\omega\vec e_\omega$$

Therefore we can say that $\vec e_l=\vec e_\omega$.
Since the angular momentum vector is a conserved quantity, it doesn't change with time, and therefore we can also say $L=\lambda \omega$

My question is: it is obvious that $\vec e_\omega$ changes during the rotation. Since this is a principal axis, $\vec L\|\vec \omega$, therefore $\vec L$ also changes direction. Is the change in the direction of $\vec L$ due to the torque by the gravitational force, and would the direction of $\vec \omega$ and thus $\vec L$ change under no gravitation, if yes, why?

Comment: Recommended resources for the intermediate axis theorem: - 2020 Youtube video by David Brown The [Dzhanibekov effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h4zlDRjV0c), equations and simulations - 2018 Article by Nicholas Mecholsky [Analytic formula for the geometric phase of an Asymmetric top](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03867v2)

Comment: $\mathbf L$ doesn't change. The conservation of angular momentum in a rigid body leads to the decomposition $\mathbf L = \mathbf I  \boldsymbol \omega$. $\mathbf I$ changes as $\boldsymbol \omega$ changes.